# R: rewrite loop using sapply

Tags: r

I got this loop:

```
for(i in E(g)){
    a = ends(g, i)[1]
    b = ends(g, i)[2]
    source_neighbors = neighbors(g, a)
    target_neighbors = neighbors(g, b)
    num_overlap_neighbors = length(intersection(source_neighbors, target_neighbors))
    print(num_overlap_neighbors)
}
```

`g` is a gml graph, I was using igraph package. I want to rewrite it as a function, use `sapply()` to apply the function to `E(g)` to get a vector as output.

Comment: There are countless examples of how to write `lapply`/`sapply` loops on this site. We really don't need another question/(self)answer pair for this.

Answer (score -2):

```
results=sapply(E(g), function(i){
  a = ends(g, i)[1]
  b = ends(g, i)[2]
  source_neighbors = neighbors(g, a)
  target_neighbors = neighbors(g, b)
  num_overlap_neighbors = length(intersection(source_neighbors, target_neighbors))

  return(num_overlap_neighbors)
})
print(results)
```

Comment: please explain more.